# Who was Guillaume Maran?

Tags: ho.history-overview

This week I visited the Capitole de Toulouse, where probably the most famous statue for us math people is Pierre de Fermat. But I found another statue of a mathematician: Guillaume Maran. He must be important, at least at that time, to be memorialized in the city hall. But all information I can find online says that he was a lawyer in Toulouse. I don't know if this is the same person as the statue. I can't find his date of birth/death or any of his work. Do you know anything about him?

[image]

**UPDATE:** I went again and took a picture of Emmaneul Maignan. But I don't understand the description under his name:
[image]

$    $

Comment: Probably this one: http://tolosana.univ-toulouse.fr/fr/auteur/077500385 . But why "mathématicien"?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I found the same page too. Or mathematician=lawyer at that time? :)

Comment: What other heads are hanging nearby? Is he surrounded by mayors or by actual mathematicians?

Comment: @darijgrinberg He is the last one in that hall. I don't remember whose statue is next to him, but not mathematician. There are only two mathematicians, Fermat and Maran.

Comment: Fermat was a lawyer too (and a councillor in the parliament)... so this may be the actual pattern.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That's my guess too, but I want to make sure(find a proof) for it :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg See the list of "other heads" here: https://books.google.com/books?id=GdeWnR4eeCQC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=guillaume+maran+and+pierre+fermat&source=bl&ots=Wv_dF6oiwY&sig=6zvCjVEQZ47XV9paO3mtws8ovug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBjaHQ_efUAhVB6CYKHRFHBQ0Q6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=guillaume%20maran%20and%20pierre%20fermat&f=false

It looks like you found a right person and he was, indeed, a "professeur de droit" (professor of law). Whether he had anything to do with mathematics remains a mystery to me.

Comment: indeed, here is another [source, scroll down to footnote 3](https://books.google.nl/books?id=PQtLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=guillaume+maran+capitole+de+toulouse&source=bl&ots=p2xXX60_wU&sig=DVBBIFawVEMKELUCPLJoRSBjniI&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=guillaume%20maran%20capitole%20de%20toulouse&f=false) that explicitly states that the lawyer Guillaume Maran (1539-1621) has a buste in the Capitole de Toulouse

Comment: Thanks @fedja and CarloBeenakker for the google books hint; that's quite a useful trail. Here's his opera omnia: https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=1PFDhHUDG7wC&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=en_GB&pg=GBS.PP1 . But it looks like law as far as the eye can see. Can anyone verify whether this is a full collection of his works? Also, a somewhat tangential but more useful question: How do you download a freely available book from Google Books?

Comment: @darijgrinberg -- you'll need to sign in to your Google account, and then "Play" is your repository of paid and free content from Google Books; I don't  think you can download it separately from your Google Play repository.

Comment: the inscription under E. Maignan's buste refers to the monastic order of the [Minimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(religious_order)), where Maignan had a function as "prior general"; this agrees with what is said on his [Wikipedia bio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel_Maignan), where he is referred to as a "Catholic Minimite theologian".

Comment: Another famous scientist belonging to the order of the Minimes was [Marin Mersenne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marin_Mersenne), who met Pierre de Fermat and corresponded with him.

Comment: one tangent comment that may be relevant: the statues are rather recent, from 1892, since the original ones from 1674 were destroyed in a fire; it may well be that knowledge of "who is who" had faded a bit by that time.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - maybe your suggestion is the right one: if the gallery has been reconstructed after two century (and without photos...) it may happened some mismatches regarding now (in 1892) "obscure" people that were "notable" (in 1600) ones.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For an authoritative answer, I contacted the professor of history at the University of Toulouse, [Jacques Krynen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Krynen), who has written a [biography](http://publications.ut-capitole.fr/18901/) of Guillaume Maran. His response [*] to the puzzling inscription on Maran's statue in de Salles des Illustres strengthens the case that it was an error. My (unsubstantiated) guess is that this happened when the 17th century statues were reconstructed in 1892 after having been destroyed by a fire a few years earlier (as described [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitole_de_Toulouse#Salle_des_Illustres)).

[*] *Il y a bien longtemps que je ne me suis pas rendu salle des illustres... en  tout état de cause Guillaume Maran était professeur de droit. Pas mathématicien!* (I have not been to the hall of celebrities for quite some time... in any case, Guillaume Maran was professor of law. No mathematician!)

Answer (score 17):

Guillaume Maran was a lawyer but not a mathematician. 
See this [page](http://data.bnf.fr/documents-by-rdt/15106081/70/page1) from the Bibliotheque nationale de France for some of his 
work.

But there should be a mathematician/physicist/theologian bust in the gallery: [Emmanuel Maignan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel_Maignan). The presence of the bust is mentioned in that [source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RVDBrNo36O0C&pg=PA438&lpg=PA438&dq=guillaume%20maran%20mathematicien&source=bl&ots=euIi2x_gJr&sig=_uEqly7hlmNWPKD8mZX0x2G7T0g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizw4G4hOjUAhXhJcAKHb5JAs4Q6AEITTAL#v=onepage&q=guillaume%20maran%20mathematicien&f=false) and in the [book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GdeWnR4eeCQC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=guillaume%20maran%20and%20pierre%20fermat&source=bl&ots=Wv_dF6oiwY&sig=6zvCjVEQZ47XV9paO3mtws8ovug&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=guillaume%20maran%20and%20pierre%20fermat&f=false) mentioned by Fedja.

So may be the similarity of the names of the two great men have contributed to attributing the virtues of one to the other.

Comment: this explanation seems strange; the local authorities must have deliberated extensively on whom to place in this hall, and with what honorary titles to designate their heroes; a mixup of names seems so unlikely to me, it must have been a deliberate decision

Comment: As a french person, those names sound really different so I can hardly see how the city hall could mistake one for the other.

Comment: As a french person, those names are similar enough to mix them up easily! *"What did you do with the Maran bust? Oh sorry the Maignan bust?"*

Comment: In the first source provided, the mathematician name is spelled Emanuel Magnan. The spelling from the XVIIe century is different from today French. The pronunciation is also very different. Actually, the language spoken in Toulouse (langue d'oc) was different from the one spoken in Paris (langue d'oi). Intellectuals were writing in Latin. Descartes (1596-1650) is one of the very first french intellectual who started writing in french. Maignan's work is in Latin.

Comment: @Max They're different enough that, even with my bad French accent, if I said "Maran", you'd never think I'd said "Maignan" or vice-versa. But the names are similar enough that, if we spoke about Maran and Maignan in the morning, it wouldn't be surprising if I'd forgotten which was which by dinner time.

Comment: the fact that Maignan's buste refers to him as a Catholic Minimite Prior, seems to rule out a simple mixup of inscriptions...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : It seems that Maignan was indeed a Catholic prior as well as a mathematician. I could imagine a committee discussing whether to put down both professions or just one, and perhaps changing its mind a couple of times. Perhaps their final decision was to put both, but their message got garbled in transmission, leading an artisan to inscribe "mathematician" under the unfortunate Maran.

Comment: Unfortunate Maran? In that he wasn't a mathematician?  I should think fortunate in that now many will remember Maran as one. Gerhard "Embrace And Accept The Confusion" Paseman, 2017.07.05.

Answer (score 6):

The "[minimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(religious_order))" was a particular religious order that existed at the time, and is frequently mentioned in 17th century sources.  It seems that he was a religious authority (prieur is somewhat less than an abbé ([abbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbot)) for the order.

Comment: I am not sure why Maran is referred to as a mathematician.  On the other hand many clerics at the time also dabbled in mathematics. A jesuit friend of Fermat's named Lalouvere did some work related to the cycloid (and even got in trouble with Pascal over this).

Comment: the complete works of Maran are [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=1PFDhHUDG7wC&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=en_GB&pg=GBS.PP1) --- I went through them, it's all law, nothing even remotely related to the natural sciences or to math.

Comment: Since Maran was at Toulouse it is possible that he was friendly with Fermat and perhaps even taught mathematics, which may have led to him being described as a mathematician. @CarloBeenakker

Comment: Maran died when Fermat was 14...

Comment: The BNF entry lists among his works a text on the necessity of re-establishing the university. His personal page refers to him as "professeur at Toulouse" but I am not sure if this has the meaning of "professor" or not. Also, according to the traditional dating Fermat was 20 at the time. @CarloBeenakker

Comment: The covent of *Minimes* is well-known in Toulouse. Claude Nougaro mentions it in his famous song ``Toulouse''. Of course, in French.